# 'Size to content' in Visual Studio resource editor and Luna/Windows 7/Classic theme

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, resources, themes

I've been having problems with text being truncated from static controls when I run my app on Windows 7, even though it shows fine on my development machine which runs XP with Classic Look (Windows 98).

I decided to make an experiment, and loaded my project in Visual Studio on a Win7 machine, and when I clicked 'Size to content' on a static control, its width became bigger, even though I had used 'Size to content' on Visual Studio with Classic Look theme.

I know that the resource editor uses real window controls to show you the dialog, and they are painted with whatever theme is set on your machine.

Is it possible that 'Size to content' depends on what theme you have set? With what theme should I test to make sure text always fits in the static control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just off the cuff here, but it sounds like "size to content" occurs at design-time rather than run-time. So if you design on Windows 7, it will size to content there. Look in the *.design.* file and you should see the size of each control assigned as an integer, so the size does not change based on the run-time environment.

**QUICK ANSWERS:** Leave lots of extra space or move to WPF.